# Where is $ref allowed in OpenAPI 3.0 specification?

Tags: rest, openapi, specifications

For our development purposes we often need to reuse definitions as much as possible from a linked specification document.

However [Swagger's OpenAPI 3.0 documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/using-ref/) only says the following:

> A common misconception is that `$ref` is allowed anywhere in an OpenAPI specification file. Actually $ref is only allowed in places where the [OpenAPI 3.0 Specification](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md) explicitly states that the value may be a reference. For example, `$ref` cannot be used in the info section and directly under paths

and the link to specification is, of course, a generic one.

So, I am wondering - is there a list compiled by someone - where specifically using `$ref` is allowed?